# Capture error from npm's python-shell

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm trying to write a program with node.js that takes in a string and runs it as python code. I then send the output of the python code to a react frontend. I have the python code successfully executing and returning the output upon successful completion of the program. However, when the python code does not execute successfully, I am unable to capture the error message and return it in a HTTP response.

The relevant code is

```
if(err){
    console.log("error is:");
    console.log(err);
    console.log(Object.keys(err));
    res.send({ result: err });
    return;
 }
```

The output this code produces is

```
error is:
   { Error:   File "tmp.py", line 2
       if __name__ == '__main__': print(main())
        ^
   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

       at PythonShell.parseError (/Users/ruiaguiar1/Desktop/interview_helper/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:191:17)
       at terminateIfNeeded (/Users/ruiaguiar1/Desktop/interview_helper/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:98:28)
       at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/ruiaguiar1/Desktop/interview_helper/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:89:9)
       at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
     executable: 'python',
     options: null,
     script: 'tmp.py',
     args: null,
     exitCode: 1 }
[ 'executable', 'options', 'script', 'args', 'exitCode' ]
```

The odd part about this is that

```
console.log(Object.keys(err));
```

logs

```
  [ 'executable', 'options', 'script', 'args', 'exitCode' ]
```

I'm not sure where the "Error" field went, or how I can take that field and send it in `res`

Comment: Try `error.stack`.

Comment: Do you mean err.stack?

Comment: Yes the `stack` field should contain the [error stack](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_error_stack)